# JOIN tables with condition to return different values in same column

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following tables and columns to join with:

```
 1. CUSTOMERS: customer_id,source_system

 2. ALERT_CASE_HEADER: customer_id,data_source_id

 3. DATA_SOURCE:id,name
```

The query is to retrieve CUSTOMERS.source_system, both customer_id in tables CUSTOMERS and ALERT_CASE_HEADER are linked.
However, if `DATA_SOURCE.name='Interactive'`, the source system should defaulted as '`NIL`', both columns `data_source_id and id` are linked.

I am thinking to join them up, but seem no relationship in between CUSTOMERS and DATA_SOURCE to determine whether it's 'Interactive' or not

```
SELECT SOURCE_SYSTEM FROM CUSTOMERS CUS INNER JOIN
ALERT_CASE_HEADER ACH ON ACH.CUSTOMER_ID = CUS.CUSTOMER_ID INNER JOIN
ALERT_CASE_HEADER ACH ON ACH.CUSTOMER_ID = CUS.CUSTOMER_ID WHERE
ACH.DATASOURCE_ID=(SELECT DS.ID FROM DATA_SOURCE DS WHERE
DS.NAME='Interactive');
```

Above query has been fixed, so i put it as one of the subquery as below.This query return the count of each STATUSES.Name and group by CUSTOMERS.Source_System and ORGANIZATION_UNITS.ORGUNIT_CODE. The expected result is to display all the counts including DATA_SOURCE.Name='NA'.Due to subquery return more than one row, the query doesn't fit the purpose.

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT CASE WHEN DS.NAME = 'Interactive' THEN 'NA' ELSE CUS.SOURCE_SYSTEM END AS SOURCE_SYSTEM
  FROM CUSTOMERS CUS
  INNER JOIN  ALERT_CASE_HEADER ACH ON ACH.CUSTOMER_ID = CUS.CUSTOMER_ID
  INNER JOIN DATA_SOURCE DS ON ACH.DATASOURCE_ID = DS.ID),
  ORG.ORGUNIT_CODE AS ORGANIZATION_UNITS,
 SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN S.NAME = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
  END
  ) AS PENDING, 
 SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN S.NAME = 'New' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
  END
  ) AS NEW, 
 SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN S.NAME = 'Investigation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
  END
) AS INVESTIGATION,
 SUM(
  CASE
     WHEN S.NAME = 'Escalated' THEN 1 ELSE 0
  END
) AS ESCALATED,
  SUM(
  CASE
     WHEN S.NAME = 'Recommend' THEN 1 ELSE 0
  END
) AS RECOMMEND,
  SUM(
  CASE
     WHEN S.NAME = 'Reopen' THEN 1 ELSE 0
  END
) AS REOPEN

 FROM
STATUSES S
JOIN ALERT_ITEM AI ON S.ID = AI.STATUS_ID
JOIN ALERT_CASE_HEADER ACH ON AI.ENTITY_KEY = ACH.ALERT_KEY
INNER JOIN ORGANIZATION_UNITS ORG ON ORG.ID = ACH.CUSTOMER_ORGUNIT_ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS CUS ON CUS.CUSTOMER_ID = ACH.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE AI.ENTITY_NAME = 'Active Alert'
GROUP BY ORG.ORGUNIT_CODE,CUS.SOURCE_SYSTEM;
```

Comment: yes, tag removed. it's oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do a straight series of joins, and then use a `CASE` expression to render the final value of the source system:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ds.NAME = 'Interactive' THEN 'NIL' ELSE c.SOURCE_SYSTEM END AS SOURCE_SYSTEM
FROM CUSTOMERS c
INNER JOIN ALERT_CASE_HEADER ach
    ON ach.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN DATA_SOURCE ds
    ON ach.DATASOURCE_ID = ds.ID
```

As a note, you might want to make one or both of the above joins `LEFT JOIN` if you suspect that records might be filtered off due to not matching the other table.  Also, in your original query you were joining twice to `ALERT_CASE_HEADER`, which is unnecessary.

Comment: The query is working fine, but when I put this entire query as a subquery of another main query, due to subquery return more than one row, it doesn't fit the main query

Comment: That sounds like the topic of another question.  I can't read your mind.  I have answered as much as I can given your information.

Comment: If your follow up is minimal, then update your question.  The error you describe is a common one and may have a quick fix.

Comment: I won't answer this here because the edit invalidates everything else you asked earlier.

Comment: don't worry, i have fixed and get what expected, many thanks.